# Angular 5 - Animation not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation, angular5

I have an animation that's supposed to slide in and slide out when I switch between components, but it's not working. 
So when you switch from component the one you see right now should slide to the left, while the one you want to load comes sliding from the right.

Excuse my terrible drawing but I hope this makes more sense:
[image]

This is my code:

**checklist.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {animate, style, transition, trigger} from "@angular/animations";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-checklist',
    templateUrl: './checklist.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./checklist.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    animations: [
        trigger('animation', [
            transition('void => *', [
                style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
                animate(1000)
            ]),
            transition('* => void', [
                animate(1000,
                    style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
            ]),
        ])
    ]
})
export class ChecklistComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() page = 'main';

    @ViewChild('modalElement') modalElement;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onPage(page: string): void {
        this.page = page;
    }
}
```

**checklist.component.html**

```
<ng-template #modalElement let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{ 'Checklist'| translate }}</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
            <app-checklist-main *ngIf="page == 'main'" [@animation] (page)="onPage($event)"></app-checklist-main>
            <app-checklist-view *ngIf="page == 'view'" [@animation]></app-checklist-view>
            <app-checklist-mutate *ngIf="page == 'mutate'" [@animation]></app-checklist-mutate>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="c('Close click')">{{ 'Close'| translate }}</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onConfirm($event)">{{ 'Confirm'| translate }}
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Anyone got any idea why it's not working??

**EDIT:**

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enethh

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have found that animations do not fire correctly on component tags that are not displayed as `block`. Update your template to the following and you should see your animations run:

```
<div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
  <app-checklist-main style="display: block" *ngIf="page == 'main'" [@animation] (page)="onPage($event)"></app-checklist-main>
  <app-checklist-view style="display: block" *ngIf="page == 'view'" [@animation]></app-checklist-view>
  <app-checklist-mutate style="display: block" *ngIf="page == 'mutate'" [@animation]></app-checklist-mutate>
</div>
```

This is because the component is displayed as `inline` by default and according to the [Spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element) animations do not run on those elements.

Comment: What if the element according to the design spec has alternate between `display: flex` and `display: none`; is there any hack?

Comment: @sudo_kaizen I think the hack would be to have the element do `display: none` as an `*ngIf` and then the first tag inside the element should have `display: flex`

Comment: @TeddySterne I'll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

1. Your transitions have placeholders :

   ```
    'void => *' => ':enter'
    '* => void' => ':leave'
   ```
2. You don't have states in your animations. If you don't have states, you can't use transitions.
3. You can remove the braces of your animation attributes :

   ```
     [@animation] => @animation
   ```
4. You current "animation" is just a change of style
5. I will use `opacity` instead of `transform` so that you can see the animation, because with your animation and without knowing your page layout, I'm not sure you will see it otherwise.
6. I will use a cubic bezier function because I like it.

So here is a correct animation :

```
trigger('animation', [
  state('void', style({ opacity: 0, })),
  state('*', style({ opacity: 1, })),
  transition(':enter', animate(`1000ms ease-out`)),
  transition(':leave', animate(`1000ms ease-in`))
])
```

Now you can test that, and replace `opacity` and get rid of the cubic bezier function (if you want to).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sadly it does not work. It's just as before, it does wait the 1000ms, but no animation...

Comment: Well... I don't think I can. This is part of a bigger project and it uses a lot of custom middlewares, components etc. to work. A lot of it is confidential, so to make this work in an example would take me hours up on hours to strip everything down and to make it work in an example envoirment. What I can do is make demo video's or screenshots. I can also provide more code if you need.

Comment: That's why it called a minimal & verifiable example :D You only create a component with the same style and the same layout, then you put a button that changes your `ngIf` condition. And I can't see images (corporate proxy), and we will have a hard time if you don't provide me something that I can play with ...

Comment: Okay, I will do my best. Hang on.

Comment: I have added an example to my question.

Comment: That's crazy, I've never seen this issue before. Your components respect the delay given, they're just not animated. I thought the lacked the `transition-property` attribute, but no ... You should open an issue on the official Angular repo with that stackblitz, I think they could help more than here !

Comment: (I'll keep trying, but I honestly don't see the issue there)

Comment: Hmmmm... Okay xD I will do that.

Comment: I have opened an issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23362

Comment: Thank you, I'll follow it and see what the issue is !